# My liquid looks like tiny balls not like a liquid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I made a liquid animation. It looks good, but it looks like tiny balls instead of liquid.[image: Blender output of what it looks like]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome, I would recommend to add more detail to the question, as for example which version of Blender you used, and maybe some details about the settings in your scene. You can use the [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/208190/edit) function to add these details and make it easier to solve your problem. The answer I wrote explains the possible situations, of which depending on a more detailed question maybe one might have been enough. The risk of the question being closed and you not getting help increases with lesser information by default.

Answer (score 5):

While I can't say which version you use, I can be sure that you use a version of Blender that uses Mantaflow.

There are still some unknowns, so I try shine some light on the possibilities.

1. You use the **Replay** default setting of the "Domain-Cache"->**Type**:
   [image: Domain type set to replay]
   With this you will not be able to scrub through the timeline as each frame needs to be simulated, BUT it's still possible to activate the **Mesh** option:
   [image: Mesh simulation active]
   Beware that for this to show properly the domain-object must **not** be set to be displayed as "Bounds", else you would not see any form of geometry. With this setting you can run the simulation and should (slower then without the Mesh active) see the fluid shown as geometry. This is nice to get an idea and fine tune the simulation.
2. Should you have set the "Domain-Cache"->**Type** to any other of the available options like **Modular**, then you need to bake the simulation and by default the **Mesh** won't be baked along with it. That is to say, once the liquid is baked to the point you showed, all you need to do is activate the **Mesh** subpanel and in this panel will be a **Bake Mesh** button:
   [image: Bake option in the Mesh subpanel]
   This button won't be there if in "Domain-Cache"-**Type** **Replay** mode. And the button will be greyed out if the simulation is not baked beforehand. Thus first bake the liquid, then you can bake the mesh. And different then in the 1st mentioned solution, you can not see the mesh simulated along with the blue particles in one go.
   There is a final "Domain-Cache"-**Type** option **All**, which essentially on pressing the **Bake All** button:
   [image: Bake All option shown only if Domain-Cache-Type is set to "All"]
   This will simulate/bake all activated options in one fell swoop. While it may safe the separate baking and clicking, it may be most helpful for all set up(after trial and error and finetuning) simulation settings as a QoL option.


   Happy Blending.

*The pictures are taken from the 2.93 alpha version, BUT the differences to the latest stable version are not big enough and should not cause any confusion.*

Answer (score 4):

The mesh of a liquid-simulation needs to be activated seperately, and is not turned on by default. (probably for performance reasons)

Make sure that you have the "Mesh"-option in the physics tab of your domain object anabled.

[image: mesh option for fluid sim]

Comment: When I activated "Mesh" checker - the liquid is generated as a mesh in viewport. But on the render it is stil displayed as spheres (a source mesh object)...